# try to install Tango+D2 but compile with error symbol undefined (Window)

Tags: d, phobos, tango

I try to use Tango and Phobo together in D2 and I downloaded the package from [link](https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2) and follow its installation [process](https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2/wiki/Installation#linux-gdc).

But it has only Linux installation but not windows.

This is what I do.

1. Visual-D and DMD already installed. [link](http://dlang.org/download.html)
2. I save the file to c:\Tango-D2-d2port
3. modify my C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\sc.ini as followed

   > [Version]
   >   version=7.51 Build 020
   >
   > ; environment for both 32/64 bit
   >
   > [Environment]
   >
   > DFLAGS= -IC:\Tango-D2-d2port\ -L-LC:\Tango-D2-d2port\ "-I%@P%....\src\phobos"  "-I%@P%....\src\druntime\import"
   >
   > ; optlink only reads from the Environment section so we need this redundancy
   >   ; from the Environment32 section (bugzilla 11302)
   >
   > LIB="%@P%..\lib"
   >
   > [Environment32]
   >
   > LIB="%@P%..\lib"
   >
   > LINKCMD=%@P%\link.exe
   >
   > [Environment64]
   >
   > LIB="%@P%..\lib64"
   >
   > DFLAGS=%DFLAGS% -L/OPT:NOICF
   >
   > LINKCMD=%VCINSTALLDIR%\bin\link.exe
4. I compile my code using following shell script file and I use dmd2\windows\bin\shell.exe to execute.

   > DMD=C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\dmd
   >
   > DFLAGS=
   >
   > $(DMD) Main.d -debug -L+C:\Tango-D2-d2port\libtango-dmd
5. My sample code from the installation page mentioned above.

   > import tango.io.Stdout;
   >
   > void main()
   >
   > {
   >
   > ```
   > Stdout("Hello from Tango!").nl;
   > ```
   >
   > }
6. error message.

   > shell 1.05
   >
   > C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\dmd Main.d -debug -L+C:\Tango-D2-d2port\libtango-dmd
   >
   > OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.12
   >
   > Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2010  All rights reserved.
   >
   > http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
   >
   > Main.obj(Main)
   >
   > Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D5tango2io6Stdout12__ModuleInfoZ
   >
   > Main.obj(Main)
   >
   > Error 42: Symbol Undefined      _D5tango2io6Stdout6StdoutC5tango2io6stream6Format20__T12FormatOutputTaZ12FormatOutput
   >
   > Main.obj(Main)
   >
   > Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D5tango2io6stream6Format20__T12?Outp垿aZ?7newli嘜FNdZC銅
   >
   > Main.obj(Main)
   >
   > Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D5tango2io6stream6Format20__T12?Outp垿aZ?5printMFYC酷
   >
   > --- errorlevel 4

I have been trying for 1-2 weeks already and this is the best I can get after I looked up many places for reference but are all futile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now.
1. I have to use the one-click installation instead of using the 
zip file
2. the correct version:
DFLAGS=-IC:\Tango-D2-d2port\ -L+C:\Tango-D2-d2port\ 
"-I%@P%....\src\phobos" "-I%@P%....\src\druntime\import"

there is no double -L as described in the tango installation 
website. It should be a typo.
3. $(DMD) Main.d -debug -L+C:\Tango-D2-d2port\libtango-dmd.lib <-- better to add .lib to specify which file.

Thank you.